# java.util.zip.ZipException: incomplete literal/length tree

Tags: java, zip

I have this problem when I try to deploy my webapp(name:auditadmin.war) on tomcat 5.05.

I did the following:auditadmin.war was already deployed & working fine.Then I edited one jsp page rebuilt it using ant & deployed the new war file.Till then I am getting the error mentioned below.

### The stack trace is :

```
INFO: Installing web application at context path /auditadmin from URL file:C:/Pr
ogram Files/CA/eTrust Audit/jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28/webapps/auditadmin
Jul 6, 2006 11:46:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error in dependencyCheck
java.util.zip.ZipException: incomplete literal/length tree
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:140)
        at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:139)
        at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.read(JarInputStream.java:159)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:220)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:277)
        at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.getBytes(JarInputStream.java:88)
        at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.<init>(JarInputStream.java:65)
        at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.<init>(JarInputStream.java:43)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.ExtensionValidator.getManifest(ExtensionVali
dator.java:368)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.ExtensionValidator.validateApplication(Exten
sionValidator.java:187)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4
187)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase
.java:823)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:80
7)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:595)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostDeployer.install(StandardHostDep
loyer.java:277)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.install(StandardHost.java:832)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:625
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:431
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:983)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java
:349)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(Lifecycl
eSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1091)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:789)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1083)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:478
)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:4
80)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:231
3)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:556)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:324)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:287)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:425)
Jul 6, 2006 11:46:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
Jul 6, 2006 11:46:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context startup failed due to previous errors
```

Can anyone please help me out?

Regards,
Vijay

Answer (score 1):

The [API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/InflaterInputStream.html) says that the ZipException gets thrown because of an error in the zip format. So my guess would be that something went wrong with building the war. I don't think that the edit of the file had a direct influence. Are you sure you used the same build script?

Answer (score 1):

Your `ZIP`/`WAR`/`EAR`/`JAR` file is corrupted.